# Why doesn't my next modal.show() not always work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have two **Bootstrap Modal**'s in my **Template.PageName.helper** `Meteor.callPromise()` that I would like to fire-up in a specific order. The order being: `modal.hide('loadingPageAnimation')` followed by `modal.show('c2bNotifications')`.

By default, `modal.hide('loadingPageAnimation')` is activated in the page **Router.route('/page')** by `modal.show('loadingPageAnimation')`

This successfully displays the `modal.show(loadingPageAnimation)` while (**in my helper**) my `Meteor.CallPromise()` is awaiting **results**:

**../client/main**

```
Meteor.callPromise('c2b').then(
  function(results) {

    //### When results comes through, Modal.hide('loadingPageAnimation') 
    Modal.hide('loadingPageAnimation');

    //### then Modal.show('c2bNotifications' along with results message)
    Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results};

  }).catch( function(error) {
    alert("Error!");
  }
);
```

The problem here is that, when the `Meteor.callPromise('c2b')` returns results, the `Modal.hide('newLoadingModal');` is successfully hidden, but the `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results});` only shows **sometimes**  and sometimes it **does not show**. I would like some consistency in `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results});` always showing/working. Can anyone explain why this happens and perhaps give a better coding solution whereby `Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results});` is forced to show?

Find below my template file.

../client/main.html

```
<template name="c2bNotifications">
  <div class="modal fade makeAnOffer">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content modal_MakeAnOffer">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Notification </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id = approvedMsg > {{msg}} </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer c2bNotifications">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="paymentNotificationClose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Looking forward to your help

Comment: you should use `$("#modal").modal("show")' OR `$("#modal").modal("hide")`

Comment: You can use: $('#modal').modal({show:false}); to init the modal box, then use $('#modal').modal('toggle'); to show/hide it

Comment: @PankajMakwana I am using the Meteor Framework, so the `c2bNotifications` in ` Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results};` is actually a template of its own, and not an id element. Am sorry that this wasn't clear in my question

Comment: @VinhNT I am using the Meteor Framework, so the `c2bNotifications` in ` Modal.show('c2bNotifications', {msg: results};` is actually a template of its own, and not an id element. Am sorry that this wasn't clear in my question

Comment: show your template file

Comment: @PankajMakwana I updated/edited my question with the `template code`. Kindly review

Comment: Is your * c2bNotifications* template always included in the parent template or is it controlled by an `{{#if }}`?

Answer (score 2):

**First solution:** What you can do is to add a little timeout to let the first modal the time to be hidden. Then call the Modal.show().

```
{
    Modal.hide('loadingPageAnimation');

    setTimeout(function(){
        Modal.show('c2bNotifications');
    }, 1000);
}
```

The problem is that you need to wait for the first modal to hide because there is no parameter to add a callback to the Modal.hide() function with the `peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal` package. If the code above really doesn't work, you can add this code

```
Modal.allowMultiple = true;
```

**Second solution:** I see you that you are using the first modal to show a loading sign, maybe you could add this sign into the c2bNotifications, and showing it with an helper like that :

```
<template name="c2bNotifications">

<div class="modal fade makeAnOffer">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content modal_MakeAnOffer">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Notification </h4>
            </div>
            {{#if isLoaded}}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id = approvedMsg > {{msg}} </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer c2bNotifications">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="paymentNotificationClose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            {{else}}
               <!-- insert loading page animation -->
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

And your helper code should look like that:

```
Template.c2bNotifications.helpers({
    isLoaded(){
        // return true if your Meteor.callPromise succeed, otherwise false
    },
});
```

**Third solution:** 
You could try to create a homemade callback, maybe by checking if the modal exist in the DOM.